# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound (No mapping found)

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

my jsps are under WEB-INF/jsp/ , and following is my web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Checkout</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

and here's mapping of page product.jsp which i am trying to access:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/product.action")
public class ProductController {

    /**
     * Show the product selection form
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get() {
        return "products.jsp";
    }

}
```

when trying to access the page from the following link:

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/product.action
```

i am getting `404` in the browser, and i get the following warning in the console:

```
Jun 28, 2012 10:55:23 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/product.action] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myservlet'
```

am i missing something in the configuration ?
please advise, thanks.

**EDIT**: i tried adding the viewResolver bean to applicationContext with no luck:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp"/>



    <bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
   </bean>


</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was that the controller wasn't detected.
i changed the base-package from `com.myapp` to `com.myapp.controller`, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the rule whatever **Sunil** has mentioned. I see one issue in your spring configuration xml that you don't have the

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

You need this to register the `Controller` along with

`<context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp"/>`

Answer (score 2):

When you specify the RequestMapping, URI should not have extension. Dispatcher servlet  will omit it from the request URI while searching for URI mapping.

Use `@RequestMapping("/product")`
 it should work.

Second thing when you are using view resolver just return the name of the JSP file. Do not append .jsp extension, InternalViewResolver will do it for you.

Comment: i tried that and it didn't work too, do i have to change anything in the configuration or in the web.xml mapping ?

Comment: it gives me `404: description The requested resource (/subscriptions/product) is not available.`

Comment: When you are getting this error? Looks like your controller handler method is invoked but returned view is not able to find. If so when you return the view name it must be relative path.

Comment: i am getting this error when typing the link in the browser and press enter, what do you suggest to do ?

Comment: You have mentioned the 404 error for resource '/subscriptions/product', I want to understand why path contains '/subscriptions'? its not mentioned anywhere in the code. Bottom line check two things - 1. Is your controller method invoked using URL http://localhost:8080/myapp/product.action? you can check that with display some message on console. 2. returned view name from the handler method should be relative path to WEB-INF. e.g. In above 404 error product.jsp should be inside 'subscriptions' folder under WEB-INF and handler method should return /subscriptions/product

Comment: controller method is not invoked

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
   **class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"**
instead of  **class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"**

in your application context bean.

Answer (score 0):

İf you use viewResolver in context xml , you should change get method return statemant to "products" and be sure the folder hierarchy is right

Answer (score 0):

1. Change this `<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*.action</url-pattern>`
2. Check base-package name in .xml file when you learn from others tutorial

Hope it should work fine

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for this error:**
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound (No mapping found)

Simply follow these steps:

Right click on the project > Build Path > Configure Build path > Deployment Assembly > Add(right hand side) > Folder > Add your views folder > Apply and Close

Answer (score -1):

Check the package name spring-servlet.xml , if it is correctly spelled or not. That might be the issue. I faced while starting the Spring MVC