# Controller not being called in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application. After implementing    my controllers are not being called.

Although my default search.jsp opens properly

Code inside search.jsp to call a controller is

```
<a href="maintenance"><input type="button" value="Maintenance" /></a>
```

When I click on Maintenance button I get 404 Not found error.

My `spring-servlet.xml` is as follows

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="org.lacare.frc.controller" />

        <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
     <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>   


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 <property name="order" value="1" />
</bean>

<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="search"/>
```

And my web.xml is as follows

```
 <servlet>
     <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
 </servlet-mapping>
```

My controller is as follows

```
package org.lacare.frc.controller;
@Controller 
public class NavigationsController  {

    @RequestMapping(value="/maintenance", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView navigateToSearch() {
        return new ModelAndView("application"); 
    }
```

Comment: Can you include package name on NavigationController.js ?

Comment: Also, the URL that is shown in the browser in the 404 error

Comment: I added the package for NavigationController.java and              URL I execute to run the application is
          "http://MyMachineIPAddress:7001/applicationName/"

Comment: Need your `mvc:annotation-driven`.

Comment: I dont have mvc:annotation-driven in my xml

Comment: Look at this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11241292/org-springframework-web-servlet-dispatcherservlet-nohandlerfound-no-mapping-fou/21047376#21047376

Comment: add this to your application context file  <context:component-scan base-package="com.lacare.frc.controller" />